# External JAR's .ClassNotFoundException while running Executable JAR

Tags: java, jar, manifest, executable-jar

I have created a simple executable JAR Which has one external dependency (jsch-0.1.54.jar) for SFTP session creation and uploading a file.

Here is the project structure:

[image]

**When I am running the code from intellij, it's working perfectly. But when I am trying to run the JAR from powershell terminal is showing error:**

[image]

Here is the JAR file's structure:

[image]

My MANIFEST has only two lines:
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.company.Main

Artifact creation settings:

[image]

What should be done to get the "detect.jar" working from terminal?

Comment: Try to build or make it because may be intellij uses it before building it.

Comment: Built the Jar(Artifact) after everything was running fine....

Comment: how to pack all dependencies into single jar in intellij??